# Implementing push state with cached layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-history

I have a web application with a home page that contains a timeline feed like Twitter. A user can navigate to their notifications (by clicking a button) and what happens is the timeline feed is hidden from view and the notifications page is loaded via Ajax. If the user decides to go back to their homepage timeline, the notifications page is hidden and then the homepage is shown. This is my current implementation.
I was looking at this article for Twitter: https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2012/implementing-pushstate-for-twittercom.html

Where they say they achieve what I do by caching the JSON response and retrieving it later if the user requests it. I was wondering do they recreate the HTML again with the JSON response or do they cache the entire HTML page. If they cache the entire page or JSON response where do they store it? On their server or the user's local machine? Is my current design approach feasible compared to theirs?

Comment: In many cases you cache JSON and can use window localStorage .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @zergski if the JSON is cached, then how do they recreate the html content associated with the JSON data? Do they just recreate it over again? Because it doesn't seem like it

Comment: an html template for structure and JSON data to populate it. The template can also be stored in the localStorage or gotten from server ( twitter does both, depending on the circumstance ).

Comment: @zergski but wouldn't it be better to just hide the template instead of requesting it over and over from the cache. If I click the home page, and then go to notifications and back to homepage, wouldn't it make more sense to just hide that page and redisplay it if the user goes back to the home page?

Comment: Yes it does, and often you do. especially if you display notifications in a dialog. so your implementation is definitely feasible. worth noting that if use something like react for instance. using the Router, it does that auto-magically

Comment: @zergski That's interesting, how does React do it? It hides/shows automatically?

Comment: react stores all data in Objects in what they call a Virtual DOM. once the data is populated it remains unchanged unless the client reloads the page or you specifically tell it to. you decleratively trigger component states which render(or rerender) component elements from the virtual DOM

Comment: so yeah, basically it does what you're saying